# AWS Cloudformation: Setting up more than 1 condition for IpAddress

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

I am using AWS SAM which I use to deploy a lambda and integrate with an API Gateway endpoint.

For API gateway, I have something like:

```yaml
Api:
   Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
   Properties:
     Cors:
       AllowHeaders: "'Authorization,Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,X-Amz-Security-Token,X-Api-Key,X-Requested-With'"
       AllowMethods: "'GET,HEAD,POST'"
       AllowOrigin: "'*'"
     DefinitionBody:
       swagger: 2.0
       info:
         version: 1.0
         title: !Sub MyAPIGateway-${EnvironmentName}
       paths:
         /{proxy+}: # https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html
           x-amazon-apigateway-any-method:
             x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
               httpMethod: POST
               type: aws_proxy
               uri: !Sub arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${Function.Arn}/invocations
       x-amazon-apigateway-policy:
         Version: 2012-10-17
         Statement:
           - Effect: Allow
             Principal: "*"
             Action: execute-api:Invoke
             Resource: execute-api:/*/*/*
             Condition:
               IpAddress:
                 Fn::Transform:
                   Name: AWS::Include
                   Parameters:
                     Location: s3://foo/bar/latest/cidr.yaml
```

Think of `s3://foo/bar/latest/cidr.yaml`  as the file which contains all whitelisted IP's and I don't have access to update or edit it as it is managed by security.

Let's say on top of those CIDR blocks, I want to add some NAT IP's, under the `Condition` can I have something so that under the `IpAddress` element I have another entry and hardcode the NAT IP's in it so that when CloudFormation runs it merges both into a single resource policy containing IP's from both?

Right now, I deploy and manually go to Resource Policy under the API Gateway web console, add my NAT IP's, save it and redeploy it.

I would like to avoid this manual update moving forward.

On a side note, I could have my own yaml file that includes everything but I don't want to clone the `s3://foo/bar/latest/cidr.yaml` file and add my NAT IP's to it and use the cloned file in my `CloudFormation` config as I have to be updating the cloned copy too frequently if something changes in the master file as `security` may be adding/removing CIDR blocks.

Answer (score 0):

As `Statement` is a list, I added another entry to include the NAT IP's and it worked.

Something like:

```yaml
Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal: "*"
            Action: execute-api:Invoke
            Resource: execute-api:/*/*/*
            Condition:
              IpAddress:
                Fn::Transform:
                  Name: AWS::Include
                  Parameters:
                    Location: s3://foo/bar/latest/cidr.yaml
            - Effect: Allow
                Principal: "*"
                Resource: execute-api:/*/*/*
                Condition:
                  IpAddress:
                    aws:SourceIp:  
                      - "myNatIp1/32"
                      - "myNatIp2/32"
                      - "myNatIp3/32"                    
                Action: execute-api:Invoke
```

Thanks!